# Simultaneously return a response and render a file for download to the browser using Spring Rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am receiving a post request from my vendor who expects an instant response (I am using Spring Rest). I use this request to validate some transactions and allow file download to the user on the browser. My question is how can i simultaneously render that file to the browser for download and return the expected response  to my vendor. Here is my attempted solution (unsuccessful). Please help. With thanks.

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST}, value ="/listeningurl", consumes = "application/xml", produces = "application/xml") 
     public ResponseObject lodgementNotifications(@RequestBody RequesObject reqObject, HttpServletResponse response)
     {

        //do stuffs with reqObject;
        //Generate a fileUrl using some parameters from the reqObject;


                try {
                //copies all bytes from a file to an output stream

                   URL fileURL = new URL(fileUrl); 
                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) fileURL.openConnection(); 


                       InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();

               // set content type 
                   response.setContentType(fileMetaData.getContentType());
               // add response header
                   response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" fileName"));
                   response.setContentLengthLong(fileMetaData.getContentLength());
                   response.setStatus(200);                     

                    FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
                //flushes output stream
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error :- " + e.getMessage());

              }


              // Initialize ResponseObject
              return responseObject

    }
```

Comment: "Here is my attempted solution (Not working)" what is that "(Not working)" means?  And from where `fileUrl` comes from?

Comment: Not working means i did not achieve the desired output from the solution. The fileUrl is generated  using some parameters from the reqObject. By the way my point is not in being able to download the file or return a rest response. That one i can do provided that they dont occur at the same time. The challenge i am having is using the same controller method in downloading the file and at the same time return a rest response. And if not possible which other options that i can take to achieve the same @Zico

Comment: I understand that. But it is not possible to achieve that using same endpoint to download a file and consume a rest response. You need to done that by using two different endpoint.